# Pandas create ranking based on grouping criteria

Tags: python, pandas

df

```
Boat  Arrival   %Bulk  PreSales
NML   20/3/21   100     50
ABC   18/3/21   100    100 
OPQ   19/3/21   100    100
TSA   20/3/21    90     10
DEF   18/3/21   100     90
FED   19/3/21    50     50
RST   19/3/21   100     90
LMN   18/3/21    50     95
CBA   19/3/21    50     80
QPO   20/3/21    90    100
```

The above dataframe has data for goods arriving on a boat with both bulky and non-bulky goods shown in percentage. Finally, units already pre-sold.

The output should have create a ranking based on the following criteria. First criteria is arrival date.  where the dates are the same, second order priority is %Bulk and finally the third order priority is the number of Presales. The idea is to decide which goods to pick up first.

**Desired Output:**

```
Boat  Arrival   %Bulk  PreSales RANK
ABC   18/3/21   100    100      1
DEF   18/3/21   100     90      2
LMN   18/3/21    50     95      3
OPQ   19/3/21   100    100      4
RST   19/3/21   100     90      5
CBA   19/3/21    50     80      6
FED   19/3/21    50     50      7
NML   20/3/21   100     50      8
QPO   20/3/21    90    100      9
TSA   20/3/21    90     10      10
```

This solution is not getting the desired results.

```
df['RANK'] = df.sort_values(['Arrival', '%Bulk', 'PreSales'])['Arrival'].index + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right lines. I think the trick will be to use a custom `sort_values()`, Arrivals should be in `asc` order, %Bulk and PreSales in `desc` order.

```
# Sort your values correctly
df.sort_values(['Arrival', '%Bulk', 'PreSales'],ascending=[True,False,False],inplace=True)

# Reset your index
df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)

# Create your ranking
df['RANK'] = df.index+1
```

Will get back your desired output:

```
df

  Boat     Arrival  %Bulk  PreSales  RANK
0  ABC  18/03/2021    100       100     1
1  DEF  18/03/2021    100        90     2
2  LMN  18/03/2021     50        95     3
3  OPQ  19/03/2021    100       100     4
4  RST  19/03/2021    100        90     5
5  CBA  19/03/2021     50        80     6
6  FED  19/03/2021     50        50     7
7  NML  20/03/2021    100        50     8
8  QPO  20/03/2021     90       100     9
9  TSA  20/03/2021     90        10    10
```